# PayPal integration in android app

Tags: android, paypal

i have successfully integrated Paypal service in my android app but i wanna do something different. as shown in below picture product is of 10$ now when user buy this product 10$ is added to my account but i wanna transfer this 10$ to two different accounts 5$ to one and 5$ to other account is there anyway to do this please help me   [image: product activity screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new PayPal MSDK are built on top of the RESTful payments API, which at this moment is not supporting use cases of parallel /chained payments, but they will be added soon.

Util then please continue using the classic Adaptive Payments APIs or MPL (noted that MPL is not being updated as the new MSDK is replacing it)

Answer (score 0):

You can do so using adaptive payments https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

Comment: i am using new paypal sdk not MPL